# \sagestr does not produce plots and sabotages others

Tags: sagetex

For the sake of illustration, I want to plot three functions:

- linear with direct `\sageplot` invocation,
- quadratic with `\sagestr`
- and sinusoidal with `\sageplot`

However, it seems that the `\sagestr` does not produce any output. Morever, it sabotages the output of the code that follows.  What is wrong?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{sagetex}
\usepackage[a6paper,margin=2mm]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\section*{Linear}
\sageplot[width=4cm]{plot(x,-2,2)}

\section*{Quadratic}
\begin{sagesilent}
o = "\sageplot[width=4cm]{plot(x^2,-2,2)}"
\end{sagesilent}
% It does not produce plot but it sabotages one produced by the following.
\sagestr{o}

% the following output is sabotaged by the \sagestr above.
\section*{Sinusoidal}
\sageplot[width=4cm]{plot(sin(x),-2,2)}
\end{document}
```

[image]

## Edit

Actually I want to compile the following but I fails. The previous code above is the minimal of the following.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{sagetex}
\begin{document}
%==================== BEGIN ===========================
\begin{sagesilent}
output = r""
for i in range(10,7,-1):
    f(x) = exp(x)*sin(i*x)
    output += r"The function is $f(x)= %s$."%(latex(f(x)))
    output += r" The second derivative of $f(x)$ is \[ \frac{\mathrm{d}^{2}}{\mathrm{d}x^{2}} %s = %s.\]"%(latex(f(x)),latex(diff(f, x, 2)(x)))
    output += r"Here's a plot of $f$ from $-1$ to $1$:\\"
    output += r"\begin{center}"
    output += r"\sageplot[width=8cm]{plot(%s,-1,1)}"%(f(x))
    output += r"\end{center}"
    output += r"\vspace{.15in}"
\end{sagesilent}
%=================== END ==============================
\sagestr{output}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Did you just find that **sage** is a shorthand for **sa**bota**ge**? ;-)

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat: Yes. Exactly!

Comment: I can't test it but I think you are using `\sagestr` wrong. The manual states that this function can be used for functions that return LaTeX code _in Sage_. The example file contains `\sagestr{pascals_triangle(n)}`, where `pascals_triangle` is a function that contains a lot of statements similar to `s.append(r"\end{tabular}")`. Your `o` variable on the other hand does not call a Sage function that produces LaTeX code, but the variable contains LaTeX code itself - and worse still, LaTeX code that actually calls Sage again. So it's all very confusing.

Comment: Maybe you can make your use case a bit more clear?

Comment: @Marijn: See my last edit.

Comment: @MoneyOrientedProgrammer that looks a bit more like the way the function is used in the manual. However, still there is a `\sageplot` command in the output, which is not visible for the first pass of sagetex. So it would probably be more straightforward to write the for loop in LaTeX, and within that loop first call `\sagestr` for the four first lines of the loop, then call (back in the LaTeX command) the `\sageplot` part and then resume the LaTeX loop for the next plot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code for the second plot is incorrect. We can see that from running portions of the code. When the first and third plots are run there is no problem.
[image]

However, running the first and second creates a problem.

[image]

This shows up in the `.sout` file where we can see the first plot was processed without issue.

[image]

So what went wrong? **EDIT:** I had mistakenly posted that the string command was the problem in the second diagram because of how the command occurs after Sage has run. I realized that was wrong, went back and found the real issue: you used a string, and not a [raw string](https://www.askpython.com/python/string/python-raw-strings). A raw string is required because you have a backslash in the string. When I make the string a raw string, the code compiles.

[image]

Finally, the code you give in your EDIT, which you say doesn't works, actually  works; well, sort of. There's nothing wrong with the code but when I tried running it using Cocalc I got `??` and I don't know why. I ended up changing the line `for i in range(10,7,-1):` to `for i in range(10,6,-1):` and the everything worked. Then I changed the 6 back to 7 and everything was fine. Weird.

Comment: Thank you. My edit shows `??` even though I changed  it to `for i in range(10,6,-1):`. That is why I said it does not work.

Comment: I don't know why but I've gotten similar behavior recently. I have to delete all files except for the .tex file and/or change some of the lines of the code and recompile. I am able to get that code to run though it didn't initially.

Comment: I made a mistake yesterday. The issue is you used a string rather than a raw string. A raw string is required so that a backslash will be processed properly.

Comment: Even though I use raw string, I still get the same issue.

Comment: If you aren't already, use Cocalc (so our two versions are identical) to process. Copy/paste your original code, add the `r` to make the string raw, save and compile the document. It compiles with ?? for pictures. Change, the domain of one of x^2 to go from -2 to 3. Save and compile. The document now shows the all pictures with x^2 actually going from -2 to 2. Like it's looking at the previous compilation. Do you get similar behavior?

Comment: Confirmed. The same behavior. The output uses the previous plot.

Comment: I contacted Cocalc explaining the problem. Hopefully they will look into it and fix.

Comment: Thank you very much!